# How to trap in empty jtable in java netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In empty textfield !lblUser.getText().trim().equals("")  how about in empty jtable? because i confuse how to trap the empty jtable

something like this same in the jtextfield...

```
public void InputUserPass() {
    if (!lblUser.getText().trim().equals("") & !txtPass.getPassword().equals("")) {
        Login();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill-up the requirements information before saving.....");
    }
}
```

how about in jtable?

please help me..... thanks in advance...

Comment: I must say I can't understand your question... Are you asking _How can I check if a `JTable` object is empty?_ Or maybe your question is _How can I check if a `JTable` cell is empty?_

Comment: yes sir.... sorry for my english grammar.....

Comment: No need to worry and neither calling me sir, I just wanted to help you getting the answer you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see if it has any rows of data:

```
if (jTable.getRowCount == 0) {
    // the JTable jTable is empty
}
```

if the row count is 0, then it is definitely empty. Note that this does not test if the table has rows but the cells within the rows are empty. For that you'd need to get the JTable's TableModel and iterate through each cell in the rows checking the cells for data, something like:

```
public boolean isTableEmpty(JTable jTable) {
    TableModel tableModel = jTable.getModel();

    // if model has no rows -- table is empty
    if (tableModel.getRowCount == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // if model has rows, check each cell for non-null data
    for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            if (tableModel.getValueAt(i, j) != null) {
                // if any cell has data, then the table is not empty
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // all cells hold null values
    return true;
}
```